# Proving subgroups for direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Q: Let G and H be groups and GxH their direct products.
>
> > (a) Prove that {(x,e): x $\in$ G} is a subgroup of GxH
> >
> > (b) Prove that {(x,x): x $\in$ G} is a subgroup of GxG

So in order for it to be a subgroup, I need to show closure under multiplication and the existence of an inverse.

So for

---

(a)

Closure under multiplication: {(x,e): x $\in$ G} and {(x1,e): x1 $\in$ G}.

so GxH=(xx1,ee)=(xx1,e) which is in GxH. So it is closed.

Inverse:  {(x,e): x $\in$ G} and {(x$^{-1}$,e$^{-1}$): x$^{-1}$ $\in$ G}.

So GxH=(xx$^{-1}$,ee$^{-1}$)=(1,1)

Therefore, {(x,e): x $\in$ G} is a subgroup of GxH

---

(b)

Closure under multiplication: {(x,x): x $\in$ G} and {(x1,x1): x1 $\in$ G}. so GxG=(xx1,xx1) which is in GxG. So it is closed.

Inverse:  {(x,x): x $\in$ G} and {(x$^{-1}$,x$^{-1}$): x$^{-1}$ $\in$ G}. So GxG=(xx$^{-1}$,xx$^{-1}$)=(1,1)

Thus,{(x,x): x $\in$ G} is a subgroup of GxG

---

Can anyone verify? Thanks.

Comment: I think $e$, here, is the unit element of H. So speaking of e, e1 is pointless.

Comment: Alright, I was thinking something like that too as another possibility. So let me edit that.